# adding click event on Html table rows

Tags: javascript, html

I have an Html table and I'm feeding that table with data from firebase so in my Html there's no table data `td` i have tried to add on click on the table row `tr` but this is adding the click on the table header `th`

```
<div>
    <table>
         <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                </tr>
            <tbody id="table">
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <script>
  function myFunction(x) {
      alert("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex);
  }
</script>
```

the second try is `js` I have tried this and many other functions like this one but it did nothing no response no errors

```
function addRowHandlers() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var row = table.rows[i];
      row.onclick = function(myrow){
          return function() { 
            var cell = myrow.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            var id = cell.innerHTML;
            alert("id:" + id);
          };
      }(row);
  }
}
```

and this is how im feeding `td` from firebase

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
ref.on("value", function(data){
 $('#table').empty()
   var content = '';
    data.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
        if (childSnapshot.exists()){
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        console.log(childData);
        

        content +='<tr>';
           content += '<td>' + childData.username + '</td>';
           content += '<td>' + childData.phone + '</td>';
           content += '<td>' + childSnapshot.key + '</td>';
           content += '</tr>';
     };
   });
   $('#table').append(content);
});
```

how to add onClick event to each row I'm new to HTML and js languages

Comment: Use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation), add a single click event to `tbody`. In the handler function the clicked row is `event.target.closest('tr')`.

Comment: thanks, @Teemu for this answer I have searched for the Event delegation and found an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your function like

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
ref.on("value", function (data) {
    $('#table').empty()
    data.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        if (childSnapshot.exists()) {
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
            console.log(childData);
            const tr = document.createElement('tr')
            let content = ""
            content += '<td>' + childData.username + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + childData.phone + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + childSnapshot.key + '</td>';

            tr.innerHTML = content;
            tr.onclick = function () {
                alert('tr', childData.phone)
            }
            $('#table tbody').append(tr);
        };
    });

});
```

Comment: you can get the index from forEach function(item, index) {}

Comment: To get separate click events on each <td /> to get the separate details only you can turn to create separate td element by createElement and pass onclick on them